# Zoom GridView - Min and Max + Reorder Childs

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I'm searching for a way to zoom a GridView (without a SemanticZoom In and Out view).
I just want the user to be able to resize the GridView children (StackPanels) so they can decide what size they prefer (with a minimum and maximum size of course).

Also I'd like the GridView to reorder the elements.
Currently I have a horizontal scrolling GridView with two StackPanels per Column.
When you zoom out there's enough room for a third but the GridView doesn't seem to care.

I've tried to use a ScrollViewer but that just messed up the width and height of the GridView inside.

Comment: Might even suffice to bind the height of the gridview to an outer ScrollViewer but I can't find any attribute that correlates with the scaled inner height.

Answer (score 0):

By setting CanReorderItems and AllowDrop property as true you can reorder the items in GridView.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.listviewbase.canreorderitems

Regards,
Riyah Ahamed I

Comment: yeah i know that but I meant more of a rearrange new order since there are only 2 elements per column at first when I zoom out I want it to rearrange and have more than 2 elements per column.
This seems like it would work with a scrollviewer if I could set the size of the gridview fitting to the scaled inner height of my scrollviewer.

I do not want the user to be able to reorder the items.